# Creating the new package in Pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid

I figured out I need to separate all my secured view callables and templates into the self sufficient package. Of course I have no idea how to do that, since I didn't find any references about making packages or modules in the documentation. By now I have default scaffold structure suggested by Pyramid guys:

**Project** application, **project** folder within it. The project folder is a package so we have `__init__.py` file within it where we have defined configuration and of course the route mapping:

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
    """

    config = Configurator(settings=settings,
                          root_factory='project.models.RootFactory')

    config.add_subscriber('project.subscribers.add_base_template',
                          'pyramid.events.BeforeRender')

    config.add_route('home', '/')
    config.add_route('cat', '/cat/{cat_url:\w+}/')
    config.add_route('cat_page', '/cat/{cat_url:\w+}/{page:\d+}/')
    config.add_route('article_view', '/article/{url:\w+}/')

    config.scan()
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

Now suppose in admin interface I have in addition about 30 routes, so I want to separate 'em into admin package. The next step I think is to create **admin** folder under **Project** folder. But I have no idea what's the next step. How should I organize the `admin/__init__.py` file? Where to place the routes, and most important, how should Pyramid know about this package and the routes defined there?

Comment: You should read that http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/01/07/building-pyramid-applications/

Comment: There's just what I need, thanks a lot buddy!!